# VBNET clickonce publish extra files get a separate folder

Tags: vb.net, publish

I'm currently trying to publish my software to an installed executable.
My project contains an XML file used to store options, this is however installed to a folder next to that of the .exe.

This is a problem since I use `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` to find the XML document.
It works when running through Visual Studio, but cannot find the file when installed.

The file is designated as 'content', copy to output directory set to  'always'[image]

Comment: I have resolved the symptoms of the issue by having the code check if the Options.XML file exists and creating a new one if it doesn't. Would still like to know how to supply one from the start though.

Comment: In project properties, Publish tab, Application Files button, is the Publish Status for the file "Data File"?  You can change that to "Include" to put the files in the same directory as the executable, or you could see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188835/2278086) for getting the current location.